how to add a zustand slice to blacklist and prevent from persisting a slice
I've started a new project and migrated from Redux to Zustand for my state management of the app. Recently I've used Redux-Persist to persist my Redux in localStorage and now I want to execute this pattern in Zustand but the problem is I want the blacklist of the Redux-Persist here which prevent some slices being persisted but I don't know how to do it.
The code is
import { create } from 'zustand';
import { createAuthSlice } from './createAuthSlice';
import { createUserSlice } from './createUserSlice';
import { createBusinessSlice } from './createBusinessSlice';
import { persist, devtools } from 'zustand/middleware';
import { AuthState, BusinessState, UserState } from '../types/zustand';

interface RootState extends AuthState, UserState, BusinessState { }

export const useAppStore = create<RootState>()(
  devtools(
    persist(
      (set) => ({
        ...createAuthSlice(set),
        ...createUserSlice(set),
        ...createBusinessSlice(set),
      }),
      { name: 'app-store' },
    )),
)

I want that the business slice of my store not being persisted in my Zustand store but two other slices being persisted how to achieve.

UPDATE:
i've found that you can create multiple stores in a zustand integrated application
so i've defined my non-persisted store in one module and defined the persisted module in another module and now i have all slices in way that i can consume them as persisted and non-persisted
the code for non-persisted


import { create } from 'zustand';
import { createBusinessSlice } from './createBusinessSlice';
import { BusinessState } from '../types/zustandTypes';

interface RootState extends BusinessState { }

export const useNonePersistedStore = create<RootState>()(
    (set) => ({ ...createBusinessSlice(set) }),
)



and for the persisted one


import { create } from 'zustand';
import { createAuthSlice } from './createAuthSlice';
import { createUserSlice } from './createUserSlice';
import { persist, devtools } from 'zustand/middleware';
import { AuthState, UserState } from '../types/zustandTypes';

interface RootState extends AuthState, UserState { }

export const usePersistedStore = create<RootState>()(
  devtools(
    persist(
      (set) => ({
        ...createAuthSlice(set),
        ...createUserSlice(set),
      }),
      { name: 'app-store' },
    )),
)



now simply we have a persisted store and a non-persisted store
